# Java extract integers from a string containing delimiters and range symbols

Tags: java, string, split

Is there a library that can help me split a String to integers by delimiters and range marks?
for instance

```
values="32,38,42-48,84"
```

output:
int[] = 32,38,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,84

Comment: What should be the expected output?

Comment: you can use String().split(,) and do Integer.parseInt() on the individual strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to get the whole range (From 42-55 for example), then I'm not entirely sure, but you can always use Regular Expressions to find everything that's not a number . The expression could be `"[^0-9]` Then use replace and change by some character (e.g commas). Then just split by commas. Feel free to read more about this here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html (NOTE: I'm not related in any way to Vogella. I just liked the tuto :)

EDIT:
I can now see the output you want (which I believe wasn't there). If that's what you want, then find all split by commas first. After, check if you have elements in which you have a symbol (- for example), and if so, then split by it and use the numbers to create the range. Here's an example of a working code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    // your code goes here
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = scan.nextLine();
    String[] splitted = s.split(",");
    for(int i = 0; i < splitted.length;i++){
        if(splitted[i].contains("-")){
            String[] nums = splitted[i].split("-");
            int from =  Integer.parseInt(nums[0]);
            int to = Integer.parseInt(nums[1]);
            for(int j = from;j <= to;j++)
                System.out.print(j+",");
        }
        else
            System.out.print(splitted[i] + ",");

    }
```

Might not be the most efficient solution, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use builtin java functions of string class like split and contains to achieve it. In order to convert string to int use Integer.parseInt. E.g.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class SimpleParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "32,38,42-48,84";
        String[] chunks = input.split(",");

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chunks));
        List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String chunk : chunks) {
            if (chunk.contains("-")) {
                String[] rangeChunks = chunk.split("-");

                if (rangeChunks.length != 2) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid range");
                }

                for (int i = Integer.parseInt(rangeChunks[0]); i <= Integer.parseInt(rangeChunks[1]) ; i++) {
                    ints.add(i);
                }

            }else {
                ints.add(Integer.parseInt(chunk));
            }
        }

        System.out.println(ints);
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
[32, 38, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 84]
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the individual items

```
//Creates an array of numbers (e.g. "32") and ranges (e.g. "42-48")
String[] items = String.split(",");
```

Loop through the array and split into ranges if range mark exists

```
 if (items[i].contains("-")
 {
   //creates an array of two containing the start and end of range
   String[] ranges = items[i].split("-"); 
 }
```

Then for each `String` you have in your arrays, parse out the `Integer`

```
Integer parsedInt = Integer.parseInt(item[i]);
```

Lastly, convert and add the `items` to a collection like `ArrayList` then convert the ranges and loop through the range (`42-48`), adding the numbers to the collection as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have used simple String arrays ans array list for the solution:

```
String[] values_s = items.split(",")

List<Integer> values_i = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(String s: values_s){

if ( s.contains('-') ){
   int sum = 0;
   String[] g = s.split("-");
   for (int i=Integer.parseInt(g[0]); i<Integer.parseInt(g[g.length-1]); i++)
       values_i.add(i);

} else {
  values_i.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
}

}

int[] n = (int[])values_i.toArray(int[values_i.size()]);
```

That should do it.